# Cocoa (OSX) drag & drop promised files - when are they ready for use?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am trying to DnD promised files from Mac OSX applications to my own application. I am using the following:

```
NSArray *filenames = [info namesOfPromisedFilesDroppedAtDestination:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
```

(info is of NSDraggingInfo)

And indeed I get a list of filenames, which I can copy into my application.

However, I see the files aren't always complete - meaning, they are not guaranteed to be fully copied to the file system by the time I process them.

I am now looking for the right solution - how should I tell when to start processing the files? Is there some other method that returns the file names and their status?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks, 
Nili

Comment: Are you looking at the files after `concludeDragOperation:` or in `performDragOperation:`?  The source is allowed to defer writing until `draggedImage:endedAt:operation:`.

Comment: I am looking at the files in:    - (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView acceptDrop:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)info item:(id)item childIndex:(NSInteger)index;

Comment: Hmmm.  So that's the equivalent of `performDragOperation:`, but as far as I can remember/review there is no outlineView equivalent of `concludeDragOperation:` which should be called after the promise is fulfilled.  You might need to subclass `NSOutlineView` and implement `concludeDragOperation:` (calling `super` appropriately) in order to get the appropriate notification.

Answer (score 1):

Promised files don’t even start writing until you accept the file, so it’s normal that you’re seeing them only half-written.

As far as I know there’s no way to know when a file’s finished writing. Are the apps you are accepting these files from not also advertising a suitable ‘file contents’ or ‘file’ or other plain, non-promise pasteboard type? Mostly apps advertise they’ll create “promise” types are just so the Finder can drop a file into a folder the user selects without the app having to write the whole (potentially huge) file ahead of time—it’s not supposed to be for applications talking to other applications.

Comment: Unfortunately the apps I'm dragging from don't have pasteboard types. Example: Google drive, Outlook for Mac, etc.

Comment: Well, they must have SOME pasteboard types, since a file promise is a pasteboard type. Have you created a simple app that lists all the types available during a drag from these apps? I bet there are more than just file promises.